# Datatemplate binding displays nothing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've got this code:

```
<GroupBox Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignCardGroupBox}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" >
    <Label Content="{Binding MatchController.Match.TeamHome}" />
    <GroupBox.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Height="32" Width="32" Source="{Binding MatchController.Match.TeamHomeShield}" />
                <Label Content="{Binding MatchController.Match.TeamHome}" />
                <TextBlock Margin="8,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignSubheadingTextBlock}" Text="{Binding Match.TeamHome}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GroupBox.HeaderTemplate>
</GroupBox>
```

As you can see I've got a header template with a DataTemplate inside the GroupBox. The strange thing is the Label outside the GroupBox displays the value of TeamHome correctly however inside the StackPanel in the DataTemplate nothing is displayed and the binding is the same, why? Mystery of the life.

Comment: Can you show the MaterialDesignCardGroupBox style as well?

Comment: is material design in xaml, you can find it on github page here: https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MainDemo.Wpf/GroupBoxes.xaml

Comment: How does it behave without the MaterialDesignCardGroupBox style applied? And what is your GroupBox surrounded with? I suspect it's in another DataTemplate

Comment: I think I just losed my head

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your GroupBox to a datasource, then it will be available to the template.

```
<GroupBox Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignCardGroupBox}"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="0"
                DataContext="{Binding MatchController}">
         <Label Content="{Binding MatchController.Match.TeamHome}" />
         <GroupBox.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                  <Image Height="32"
                         Width="32"
                         Source="{Binding Match.TeamHomeShield}" />
                  <Label Content="{Binding Match.TeamHome}" />
                  <TextBlock Margin="8,0,0,0"
                             VerticalAlignment="Center"
                             Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignSubheadingTextBlock}"
                             Text="{Binding Match.TeamHome}" />
               </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
         </GroupBox.HeaderTemplate>
      </GroupBox>
```

Comment: datasource property not found on groupbox object

Comment: It is a typo, should be DataContext

Comment: Meant datacontext. Fixing answer now.

Comment: Note that I also changed the binding on the templated items.

Comment: Then unfortunately it sounds like something else is impacting the ability of your control to bind properly. I would try eliminating everything and take it one step at a time: aka, can I at least get the label in the data template to display, without any modifiers? Then, add the modifiers in. Repeat until something breaks, at which point you have your culprit.

Comment: the error in the compiler is: matchcontroller property not found on binding

Answer (score 0):

```
<DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Height="32" Width="32" Source="{Binding MatchController.Match.TeamHomeShield}" />
                                <Label Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.MatchController.Match.TeamHome}" />
                                <TextBlock Margin="8,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignSubheadingTextBlock}" Text="{Binding Match.TeamHome}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GroupBox.HeaderTemplate>
```

If the DataContext of your code is set on the Window element, use this code. Otherwise, just change to the type of the nearest element that has this DataContext.

Comment: Sorry! 
<Label Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.MatchController.Match.TeamHome}" />

Comment: I need to add all this content for each control or I can add something like this on groupbox? 'cause your solution worknig but too code for each control

Comment: Do as Marisa said and put a DataContext on a parent element and then binding directly to the variable wherever needed.